# css display:none for responsive web design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need advice on what's the best solution to this.

I'm doing a RWD Photo Gallery page. Basically, i'm using pretty photo if accessed through a desktop and photoswipe when accessed in mobile devices.

What i did is this:

```
<a href="large_image" class="desktop" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="sample_image" /></a>
<a href="large_image" class="mobile" rel="external"><img src="sample_image" /></a>
```

I hide (display:none) one of them depending of the screen size using media queries.
Is this a right approach, i read that using display:none will not reduce the load time. I have hundreds of photos in my gallery and i'm worried this might greatly affect the load time. Is there any good solution to this?

Comment: You should consider determining mobile vs pc on the server side and only sending the right images to the client. The load time would other wise be twice as much (assuming mobile and desktop images are different. If they are the same, loading time will be similar as HTML size is not as significant).

Comment: Is `mobile` and `desktop` loading 2 sets of different images? If they are loading the same set of image then `display: none` would work fine with no performance impact.

Comment: [This might be of interest](http://blog.cloudfour.com/css-media-query-for-mobile-is-fools-gold/) TLDR: both images will be downloaded.

Comment: A good article to read: Choosing A Responsive Image Solution: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/

Comment: The mobile and desktop class contain 1 image. So it's like 2 anchor tags for the same image just having different class and rel. Is there a way  in javascript or jquery to change the class and rel attribute if it hits a certain screen size? So i'l just be using one anchor tag?

Comment: Is the sample image is exact in both cases? You only want to avoid loading the large image when the user clicked right?

Comment: You can change the class using [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) (and .removeClass()).
For changing rel use: `$("selector").attr('rel', 'somevalue');`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two tags for this?

```
<a href="large_image" class="desktop" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="sample_image" /></a>
<a href="large_image" class="mobile" rel="external"><img src="sample_image" /></a>
```

You can achieve the same with a single tag.

```
<a href="large_image" class="desktop_and_mobile" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="sample_image" /></a>
```

Now with media query you can have the same desktop_and_mobile class on both media query and define the css property accordingly in each.

This has the advantage that you will be loading only one image, instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to have the anchor tag to call the correct lightbox when clicked, because styling the sample_img with responsive css will work as expected, no need for fancy stuff, but if i'm correct then you have 3 choices in my opinion, you can do it like you said and hide the .desktop links using media queries, since the images are exactly the same the user wont have to load again that image, and being set to `display:none` the user browser won't render that element, so the only downside is that you will have a cluttered html and it will feel muddy, but no other concern in my opinion.

Another option is to use a js code like this one, but since usually lightbox codes will have a method to add event handlers to every link they find with (with the proper formating, lets say its rel), you will have to manually trigger that event after you changed the links rel attr, or execute `adaptLinks()` before that happens, in that case, on windows resize it won't work, unless you do what i said before. For that you can check how to do it on the lightbox page, they propably have that method listed.

Here is the **code**

```
var adaptLinks = (function(){
    var $winHeight = $(window).height();
    var $lightBoxLinks = $('a.lightBox');

    return function() {  
        var isPrettyPhoto = false;

        if($winHeight < 1000){
             $lightBoxLinks
                .removeClass('desktop')
                .addClass('mobile')
                .attr('rel','external');
        } else {
             $lightBoxLinks
                .removeClass('mobile')
                .addClass('desktop')
                .attr('rel','prettyPhoto');

                isPrettyPhoto = true;
        }

        // Call the link processing method of the lightbox
        if(isPrettyPhoto) {
           $lightBoxLinks.prettyPhoto();
        } else {
          // photoSwipe method
        }

    }

})();    

$(window).resize(adaptLinks());
```

And the thir option, is use a lightbox that works both for desktop and mobiles, i think that is the right way to do it.

Good luck.